# Problem in installing X11/XQuartz in Mac 10.8.5

Tags: install, bug, xquartz

I need to install XQuartz in Mac 10.8.5.But every time when I reach the destination folder selection in installation step,it freezes and doesn't move forward.I have admin account as well but as I looked through the [net](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5418622), seems that others also have the problem.How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks for the people who provided the answer for this question.But the answer was kind of easy .That was a bug in the Mac OS 10.8.5 .I upgraded the system to OS X 10.9 and now it works perfectly!!!Many thanks for the contributions.!!!

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to install the software using `installer` on the command line. You will need to make sure that you have the XQuartz disk image mounted before performing this command:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/XQuartz-2.7.4/XQuartz.pkg -target /
```

***Edit***

Apparently, the XQuartz installer is not allowing installation on the boot drive because it is failing some pre-installation checks. This is based on the following error message that occurred when attempting to use `installer` in Terminal:

```
installer: Cannot install on volume / because it is disabled.
 installer: This update requires you to first update your system to OS-X 10.6.3
```

The installer is not recognizing the system as the correct version. Although the contents of `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` shows that the value of `ProductVersion` is set to '10.8.5', the installer does not see it this way.

It may be possible to modify the package's Distribution file to allow it to install correctly:

1. Mount the XQuartz-2.7.4.dmg disk image (assuming that it's on the Desktop):

   `hdiutil mount ~/Desktop/XQuartz-2.7.4.dmg`
2. Expand the package into a folder name XQuartz on the Desktop:

   `sudo pkgutil --expand /Volumes/XQuartz-2.7.4/XQuartz.pkg ~/Desktop/XQuartz`
3. Modify the Distribution file inside of the expanded package, to allow installation to occur (regardless of the system version):

   `cat ~/Desktop/XQuartz/Distribution | sed s/false/true/g > ~/Desktop/Distribution`
4. Move the new Distribution file into the expanded package

   `sudo mv ~/Desktop/Distribution ~/Desktop/XQuartz`
5. Flatten the modified package:

   `sudo pkgutil --flatten ~/Desktop/XQuartz ~/Desktop/XQuartz.pkg`
6. Cleanup the XQuartz folder that was expanded from the original package

   `sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop/XQuartz`

After creating the modified package on the Desktop, you may be able to double-click on the file to get it to install normally. Alternately, installing using the Terminal may also work at this point.

Comment: I doesn't work.Do I need to change anything in the command?? `target` or something?it says it is invalid

Comment: What exactly does it say is invalid?

Comment: It just freezes.It doesn't go forward.I can go backward but not forward.By the way I even tried to install it in `root` user but same problem happened

Comment: @Alex I've added additional suggestions to the answer above.

Comment: Hi,As I wrote my opinion for other question. In wont work.I think it is a problem of the company _Application Provider_  trying to push apple to include Xquartz in Mac OS 10.8.5 application!!!How is your idea?Look at here (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5418622

Comment: @Alex - what is the exact error message that you receive when you attempt to install using the Terminal command above?

Comment: `installer: invalid option -` and bla bla bla I ,tried different paths,different formats,...Am I mistyping something?How I can write the correct path?? maybe I am doing this mistake?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384409/how-to-install-a-mac-application-using-terminal). I installed Xquartz many other times for 10.8.3 without any problem but just in 10.8.5?!!!

Comment: @Alex - I apologize, but there was indeed a typo in the Terminal command above (two hyphens before the target flag). I have corrected the answer. Please attempt the corrected command that's shown above, and report back.

Comment: here is the message: `installer: Cannot install on volume / because it is disabled.
installer: This update requires you to first update your system to OS-X 10.6.3` is it not strange????!!!I have 10.8.5?!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11214/discussion-between-eddie-kelley-and-alex)

Comment: @Alex - modified the answer with suggestion on how to get around installer error.

Comment: Hi sorry the problem is still there.Many thanks for the time and efforts!!

Comment: Hi ,Please see my answer!!Because you spend a lot of time I gave you the 100 points cause it would be expired soon.

Comment: This solved my freezing problem for xquartz-2.7.11.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your comments you say you can go back, but not move forward the installer hasn't really "frozen" so perhaps the following is the rather simple solution to your problem...

I have just successfully reinstalled XQuartz 2.7.4 on Mavericks and at the **Select a Destination** screen the **Continue** button was disabled.  I had to wait a second or two and then had to select the **Install for all users of this computer** line even though it appeared to be already highlighted before I could continue.

Comment: Hi I waited around 10 min but nothing happened DD.Thats means with only patient it is not going to get fixed;). I can not select **instal for all users of this computer**

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded it from [CNet](http://software-files-a.cnet.com/s/software/12/75/11/63/XQuartz-2.7.4.dmg?lop=link&ptype=3001&ontid=2094&siteId=4&edId=3&spi=d8b1c20fbfe6232f0c8281f80d50c188&pid=12751163&psid=10912185&token=1382587404_808302ad9fef69ee1b22142037ddb358&fileName=XQuartz-2.7.4.dmg) and was able to install it without any hickup

Comment: Hi link doesn't work

Comment: @Alex Try this link: http://download.cnet.com/XQuartz-X11/3000-2094_4-10912185.html?tag=mncol;1 or search directly in CNet

Comment: sorry same problem!

Comment: Then google this: CNet XQuartz (don't know why it doesn't work... I've used the link on three different computers and it works just fine)

Comment: I mean the same problem is in installation not finding Xquartz. Yes this is also new to me.Did you see the link about same question that I had in my question text?