# Unable to install R-2.11.1.pkg and up to R-3.0.2 in Mac OSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, install, x11

I have an iMac 2013 with a Fusion Drive and OSX 10.8.5. No plans to migrate to Mavericks yet.

I have had [issues also with x11](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105886/problem-in-installing-x11-xquartz-in-mac-10-8-5/117607#117607) that I've solved with a "direct" install:

```
installer -pkg ~/Desktop/XQuartz.pkg -target / -allowUntrusted -store
```

But, when I try to install R-2.11.1 and above (I'm using R-2.10.1, and works well ;) ) I get the following message from the installer:

```
R 3.0.2 for Mac OS X 10.6 or higher (Snow Leopard build) can't be installed on this disk.
This build of R requires MAC OS X 10.6 or higher.
```

If I try from the Terminal

```
sudo installer -pkg ~/Desktop/R-3.0.2.pkg -target / -allowUntrusted -store
```

I receive this output from terminal:

```
installer: Note: running installer as an admin user (instead of root) gives better Mac App Store fidelity
installer: Warning: R-3.0.2.pkg was signed with a certificate that is not valid for store submission.
installer: Installation Check: Passed
installer: Volume Check: Fatal: Failure
```

And it fails.

What can I do? Delete some plist? Regenerate something? Reinstall Mountain Lion? I really prefer to not to have to rebuild from source.

I have had no issues installing R on my notebook with Lion.

Comment: It's a little hard in your question to parse out what you are typing and the errors that are returned. Could you make it a little clearer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried also "more options in installer" also to N/A. Did not tried Sage.

Then I tried with the re-installation of OSX 10.8.5 (Cmd-R), and then I've installed R3.0.2 without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `-store` option? You realise that if you have that then `-allowUntrusted` is ignored. To quote the man page `In this mode, no other options are supported`. That option is there to check that a package is ready to be submitted to Apple for the App Store.

Take that out.

I also discovered that failed attempts seem to leave orphan installer processes running that seem to cause trouble in later attempts - even a `kill -9` leaves them on the process stack.

Reboot your computer and then run Terminal. First go `sudo -s` so you get an actual root shell. Now `installer -verbose -pkg ~/Desktop/R-3.0.2.pkg -target /` in the root shell. Thats what worked for me under 10.9

Comment: Hi Tony, just re-did this

sudo installer -pkg ~/Desktop/R-3.0.2.pkg -target /

The answer is always the same:

installer: Cannot install on volume / because it is disabled.
installer: This build of R requires Mac OS X 10.6 or higher.

...

Comment: Added to the answer after doing some exploration.

Comment: Tony, thanks a lot, but still does not work. I did :

sudo -s and bash told me: bash-3.2# (root ok)

then I did:

installer -verbose -pkg ~/Desktop/R-3.0.2.pkg -target /


and then the answer is always the same:


installer: Cannot install on volume / because it is disabled.
installer: This build of R requires Mac OS X 10.6 or higher.

Comment: Dang. Might be a 10.8 problem as it went in fine under 10.9

It's possible all your failed attempts have left too much cruft around. At what point did it fail - what was the verbose output you got?

Comment: and not, is a (not so well) known problem. There is a solution for x11 (that I've applied) and then I go back to my original question: What can I do? Delete some plist? Regenerate something? Reinstall Mountain Lion? I really prefer to not to have to rebuild from source, but if rebuilding from source is the only option I should go there ...

Comment: verbose output:
installer: Cannot install on volume / because it is disabled.
installer: This build of R requires Mac OS X 10.6 or higher.

Comment: It is at this point that I would scrape and re-image the computer. Go right back to a clean install of the OS and test from there. You could also sidestep the entire problem and try a SAGE install :- http://www.sagemath.org/ it will give you R 3.0.2.